# What happened to the archangel Gabriel in DC Vertigo after his unfortunate encounter with John Constantine (hellblazer)?

Tags: comics, dc, vertigo-comics, hellblazer

In the Hellblazer comic, the archangel Gabriel is tricked into falling from grace by John Constantine and an angry succubus named Ellie.

I noticed he wasn't present in the Lucifer comics, so I assume that by then he was not redeemed (if ever). I would like to know what happened to him and which comics he features after his fall.

Comment: As N.R.V points out in their answer, Gabriel is currently am active character in the ongoing _Lucifer_ series, which means we're yet to see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Hellblazer #66 (Fear and Loathing, part 3), after his heart is taken and Gabriel is cast out of Heaven, he wanders the streets of London, homeless.  He doesn't appear again until, in Hellblazer #79 (Rake at the Gates of Hell, part 2), Constantine retrieves the heart and uses it to locate him.  Gabriel says,

> All I do is wander.  [..] Where once I strode the halls of paradise, now I trudge around this dungeon of a city like some shade in limbo.

In the following issue, Gabriel's heart is crushed by Satan condemning Gabriel to "damnation and agony eternal", which seems to be his last appearance; this story-line is the only one mentioned in Gabriel's entry in the 2008 Vertigo Encyclopedia.

Comment: Thank you! I have been wondering about this but for some reason I could never find anything at all. It's not exactly a happy ending though...

Answer (score 5):

Gabriel [reappeared in the *Lucifer* series](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2015/12/16/lucifer-101-what-you-need-to-know) in Dec 16, 2015 in *[Lucifer #1](http://www.vertigocomics.com/comics/lucifer-2015/lucifer-1)*.

[image: Gabriel]

> As this series begins, God is dead—and Gabriel has accused Lucifer of His murder. Lucifer had motive and opportunity, but claims he can prove his innocence. If Gabriel finds the killer and takes the culprit into custody, his sins will be forgotten, and he’ll be welcomed back to Silver City. So, despite the fact that Lucifer just opened a nightclub on Earth and is hiding a mysterious wound, the two brothers set off to solve their Father’s murder. Their investigation will span Heaven, Hell, Earth and beyond in this antagonistic buddy-cop noir with an angelic flair.

As of the April 19th, 2017 issue, *[Lucifer #17](http://www.adventuresinpoortaste.com/2017/04/19/lucifer-17-review/)*, Gabriel is still alive and well.